# Schedule tasks using Quartz and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, triggers, cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I would Like to send emails daily using Spring boot, the user specifies the time of sending, I used quartz to schedule my Job.
The recipients of emails have(id, emailAddress, deadline) The email will be sent to the people who have deadline = Today + X.. (The user specifies the X).
For example: The user specifies that X is number 1, so we're interested in people who have deadline tomorow.

Day1: the app sent emails to people who have deadline = today +1..
Day2: I want that the application send the email at Day2 to new recipients, but with the code below, the email is sent to the ones who received it in Day1, and that's not what I need.

```
@PostMapping("/scheduleEmailPeriodic")
    public ResponseEntity<ScheduleEmailResponse> SendScheduleEmailPeriodic(
            @Valid @RequestBody PeriodicNotification scheduleEmailRequest) throws Exception {
        ens.schedulePeriodicNotification(scheduleEmailRequest);
        LocalDate localDateTime = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(scheduleEmailRequest.getSendingTime());

        

        try {
            ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, localTime,ZoneId.of("Africa/Casablanca"));
            if (dateTime.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now())) {
                ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(false,
                        "dateTime must be after current time");
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(scheduleEmailResponse);
            }

            JobDetail jobDetail = buildPeriodicJobDetail(scheduleEmailRequest);
            Trigger trigger = buildJobTriggerPeriodic(jobDetail, dateTime);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

            ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(true, jobDetail.getKey().getName(),
                    jobDetail.getKey().getGroup(), "Email Scheduled Successfully!");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(scheduleEmailResponse);
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            logger.error("Error scheduling email", ex);

            ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(false,
                    "Error scheduling email. Please try later!");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(scheduleEmailResponse);
        }
    }

private JobDetail buildPeriodicJobDetail(PeriodicNotification scheduleEmailRequest) {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
        List<String> recipients = fileRepo.findWantedEmails(scheduleEmailRequest.getDaysNum());

        if(recipients.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Aucun destinataire trouvé");
        }
        String[] to = recipients.stream().toArray(String[]::new);

        jobDataMap.put("recipients", to);
        jobDataMap.put("subject", scheduleEmailRequest.getSubject());
        jobDataMap.put("body", scheduleEmailRequest.getMessage());

        return JobBuilder.newJob(EmailJob.class).withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "email-jobs")
                .withDescription("Send Email Job").usingJobData(jobDataMap).storeDurably().build();
    }

    private Trigger buildJobTriggerPeriodic(JobDetail jobDetail, ZonedDateTime startAt) {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), "email-triggers")
                .withDescription("Send Periodic Email Trigger")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder
                .repeatHourlyForever(24))
                .startAt(Date.from(startAt.toInstant()))
                .build();
    }
```

This is the email job:

```
@Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Executing Job with key {}", context.getJobDetail().getKey());
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
        String subject = jobDataMap.getString("subject");
        String body = jobDataMap.getString("body");
        String[] recipients = (String[])jobDataMap.get("recipients");
        sendMail("smsender4@gmail.com", recipients, subject, body);
        
    }
    
     private void sendMail(String fromEmail, String[] toEmail, String subject, String body) {
            try {
                logger.info("Sending Email to {}", Arrays.toString(toEmail));
                MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
                messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                messageHelper.setText(body, true);
                messageHelper.setFrom(fromEmail);
                messageHelper.setTo(toEmail);

                mailSender.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                logger.error("Failed to send email to {}", Arrays.toString(toEmail));
            }
        }

}
```

I really need Help, I need to get new recipients everyday, not to send the email to the same recipients.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending emails based on date - but you don't track when emails were sent for a particular user. So if you will send one email to user1 Today - then user1 will still be in the condition for the next day. You need to add a flag (or some other logic ) saying that email was already sent for this user

Comment: Understood! Thank you, I will try this.